# Front-end building process with bower, Grunt, npm

Tags: java, node.js, maven, gruntjs, bower

Hi it is a little bit general topic but now I come from back-end world and have to build front end applications and have some misunderstandings. So lets explain what I understand in building front-end app using bower, Grunt, npm.

When I build backend app I use *Gradle* which has its own dependency manager which is responsible for managing dependencies. OK. But when I want to build frontend application, I have to manage manually all java scripts, css etc. files.

So for that purpose I have to use **Bower** for js managing dependencies, RequireJs for Managing dependencies at runtime, Grunt for copying stuff around, running optimizers, less to css transformations. This tasks have to be triggered on change and all files to be in consistent state and not to copy js files manually and this have to be done on CI server(and in local development) am I right?

Ok but what happens after that. I have to build an war to deploy it on my tomcat for that purpose I have to use build tool like Gradle,Maven and to use all js,css, image artifacts and to package them in one war for example? Is that the purpose of bower, Grunt to make front end stuffs easy to collect?

Comment: Xelian, you can import front-end stuffs in your project via grunt(copy to compiled statics etc.), or do you want to serve your statics through nodejs server?, if so you don't need to create war file to serve statics.

Comment: I have some services provided from the backed, chick give me some data.